# Shell how to let a array as other shell args?

Tags: shell

I have two shell script a.sh,b.sh .

```
--------a.sh---------

array=(1.1 1.2 1.3)

./b.sh $array

--------end a.sh---------


--------b.sh---------

packageVersionArr=$1

for i in ${packageVersionArr[@]}; do

    echo $i

done

--------end b.sh---------

console only print: 1.1
```

where is my 1.2 and 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` is the first element, you need `${array[*]}`. See arrays in the [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html).

```
bash -x
$ array=(1.1 1.2 1.3)
+ array=(1.1 1.2 1.3)
$ ./b.sh $array
+ ./b.sh 1.1
...
$ ./b.sh ${array[*]}
+ ./b.sh 1.1 1.2 1.3
...
```

Comment: If I use ${array[*]}, is not true.  b.sh used "packageVersionArr=$1". is only get 1.1

Comment: That's because b.sh has a bug too.